# Android: Error at launch with AppBarLayout + Toolbar configuration

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-toolbar, android-search

[Link to code/repo](https://github.com/KausiAhmed/PodPlay)

I am trying to configure the AppBarLayout and the Toolbar and getting the following error at launch:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.raywenderlich.podplay/com.raywenderlich.podplay.PodcastActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22 in com.raywenderlich.podplay:layout/activity_podcast: Failed to resolve attribute at index 1: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f030003 a=-1}, theme={InheritanceMap=[id=0x7f110269com.raywenderlich.podplay:style/Theme.PodPlay.AppBarOverlay, id=0x7f11026fcom.raywenderlich.podplay:style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar, id=0x7f110075com.raywenderlich.podplay:style/Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar, id=0x7f110074com.raywenderlich.podplay:style/Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark, id=0x7f110137com.raywenderlich.podplay:style/Platform.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark, id=0x7f110136com.raywenderlich.podplay:style/Platform.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat], Themes=[com.raywenderlich.podplay:style/Theme.PodPlay.AppBarOverlay, forced, com.raywenderlich.podplay:style/Theme.PodPlay.NoActionBar, forced, com.raywenderlich.podplay:style/Theme.AppCompat.Empty, forced, android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light.DarkActionBar, forced]}
```

The `NoActionBar` style is applied to the activity to tell the system not to include the system action bar since I will be using the `Toolbar` class instead.
The `AppBarOverlay` is the style used for `AppBarLayout`.
The `PopupOverlay` is for the `Toolbar`.

`Theme.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <style name="Theme.PodPlay" parent="android:ThemeOverlay.Material.Dark.ActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
    </style>
    <style name="Theme.PodPlay.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
    <style name="Theme.PodPlay.AppBarOverlay"
        parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>
    <style name="Theme.PodPlay.PopupOverlay"
        parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
</resources>
```

Part of `activity_podcast.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.raywenderlich.podplay.PodcastActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.PodPlay.AppBarOverlay">
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.PodPlay.PopupOverlay"/>. // This is line 22 referenced in the error
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.PodPlay"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".PodcastActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.PodPlay.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

`PodcastActivity.kt`

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityPodcastBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)
}
```

[Link to code/repo](https://github.com/KausiAhmed/PodPlay)
What did I do wrong?